# Disable Stripe email receipt being triggered by CognitoForms payment form

Tags: cognito-forms

How can I stop CognitoForms sending a Stripe email receipt to customers that successfully make a Stripe payment to me?

I've managed to get payments via Stripe working on my CognitoForms.com form, and am sending a PDF receipt to customers that successfully make a payment from WebMerge.me and this PDF receipt is also working now.

I have turned off Confirmation Emails on this CognitoForms form, and I have not selected the option to "Email customers for successful payments" in Stripe itself at https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/emails so Stripe shouldn't be sending an email receipt to the customer as it is currently doing.

1. How can I stop Stripe sending an email receipt to customers that make a payment via this form?
2. Wufoo provides a specific checkbox option to enable or disable email receipts from Stripe - do you offer this?

Answer (score 1):

With Stripe-connected payment forms in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com), you can control what information is sent to Stripe by mapping billing fields:

[image]

While it may seem nice to send over the email address even if you do not want to send a receipt from Stripe, Stripe does not have a similar viewpoint.

From their API specifications:
https://stripe.com/docs/api#create_charge

> **receipt_email**
>
> The email address to send this charge's receipt to. The receipt will not be sent until the charge is paid. If this charge is for a customer, the email address specified here will override the customer's email address. Receipts will not be sent for test mode charges. **If receipt_email is specified for a charge in live mode, a receipt will be sent regardless of your email settings.**

So your best option is to not map the Email field under payment settings, and the receipt will not be sent from Stripe.

On a related note, I will add you to our list of customers who will be invited to beta test our "soon to be released" support for custom document generation.  This will allow you to send custom merged documents directly through Cognito Forms.